# How to use a global variable in #if conditional check?

Tags: c, if-statement, macros, conditional-statements

```
#define TEST
int i = 1;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
#if (defined(TEST) && i) 
    printf("it is printed");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to create another macro for `i`?

Comment: You can't. Preprocessor directives are evaluated at compile time, variables are not available at that time.

Comment: "Do I have to create another macro for i?" Yes. `i` needs to be a macro ultimately resolving to a preprocessor integer constant in order to be usable in `#if` conditionals.

Comment: Can you use an `if (i)` instead of putting that in the macro?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? What is the reason behind this question? Right now this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output if and only if both the macro and the condition on the global variable are true then do like this:

```
#if (defined(TEST)) 
if (i)
{    printf("it is printed");
}
#endif
```

Reason (agreeing with comment by Barmar):

> Preprocessor directives are evaluated at compile time, variables are not available at that time.

Comment: Preprocessing is done before the actual C code compilation

Comment: @P__J__ True. What is your point? You want the (theoretical) difference between pre-processor time and compile time discussed?

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, macro definitions are expanded during the preprocessing stage, before the actual C code compilation.

But why this code compiles and what will be the result of it.

```
#if (defined(TEST) && i)
```

1. preprocessor tests for macro definition `TEST`. As it was defined, the result of this check is `true`
2. now the preprocessor is checking if **macro definition** (not the C variable!) `i` exists. As it does not, the whole expression in the `#if` is evaluated to `false`.

Generally :

```
#if a
```

checks if macro definition `a` exists and then if its value is `!= 0`,